# Error parse Object and using Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I tried in various ways to read my most unsuccessful object.
used Gson, babble just the java,

All class are descendants of Objetc why the error happens.

[image]

```
public class InputDefault implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6755668336349284303L;
    private Object Result;
    private boolean Success;
    private String SuccessMessage;


public class InputGetInfosUser implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7433623152728612356L;

    @SerializedName("UserId")
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("UserName")
    private String userName;

    @SerializedName("Email")
    private String email;

    @SerializedName("Gender")
    private String gender;

    @SerializedName("LastLogin")
    private String lastLogin;


@GET("/")
public void getInfosUser(
        CancelableCallback<InputDefault> inPutCallSupportCancelableCallback
);
```

**ERRO 1**

```
public void sucessGetInfosUserOnListener(Object response) {
    InputDefault inputDefault = ((InputDefault) response);
    InputGetInfosUser inputGetInfosUser = null;
    String result1 = inputDefault.getResult().toString().trim();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    inputGetInfosUser = gson.fromJson(result1, InputGetInfosUser.class); //error
```

value result1

[image]

[image]

**ERRO 2**

```
public void sucessGetInfosUserOnListener(Object response) {
        InputDefault inputDefault = ((InputDefault) response);
        InputGetInfosUser inputGetInfosUser = ((InputGetInfosUser) inputDefault.getResult()); //erro
```

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to achieve and what was the error message?

Comment: @DouglasDrumond added images errors, I'm trying to make a read at my object

Comment: it seems the json content is invalid, try pasting it on http://jsonlint.com/ and see if it fails

Comment: add image JSON, JSON is valid @DouglasDrumond :(

Comment: make sure result1 contains only the internal part of json. You used ` gson.fromJson(result1, InputGetInfosUser.class);`, so you're not expecting the outer part. Your JSON should be

{
   "UserId" : 159,
   ...
}

Comment: the InputGetInfosUser.class, is exactly the expected return, as the picture [http://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Vpv.png] @DouglasDrumond